# Can't use commands from ipython or julia repls with zsh

Tags: path, ipython, julia, zsh

When I try to run a shell command in ipython or the julia repl it just says

```
shell> ls
zsh:1: command not found: ls
```

Not sure if it matters, but I have my path set in zshenv instead of zshrc so that emacs shell works.

Any ideas?

Edit:
I'm on macOS 10.14.6

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Julia doesn't use your normal shell environment, so stuff in bashrc and zshrc don't usually work either. That said `ls` does work in my julia-based shell, and I'm pretty use my julia shell doesn't use `zsh`, even though my login shell is zsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Julia, The `shell>` REPL prompt does in fact use a shell to execute its commands (on non-Windows systems).  It effectively does something like `` run(`$shell -c ls`) ``, and for most shells (including zsh) this means "non-interactive" mode and limits the number of init files that get loaded.  You want to make sure your shell is working in this mode; I'd guess that if you type `zsh -c ls` at your terminal it'll be similarly broken.

Alternatively, you can customize which shell Julia uses through an environment variable.  Setting `JULIA_SHELL=/bin/sh` is probably a safe bet — Julia uses that environment variable if it is set, otherwise it uses `SHELL`, and finally it falls back to `/bin/sh` if neither is set.

I'm not as familiar with ipython, but I'd wager it's doing something similar.

Comment: I really need to get some of my .zshrc and .zsh_alias functions into the julia shell. Its such a useful aspect of Julia, I use it a lot.